# SQLite in Android How to update values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

As far i have researched there are two ways to update the SQLite database

```
execSQL(String sql) method
```

or the:

```
update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) method.
```

in my app i'm using the `update` method option.

Basically i want to implement the the forgot password functionality. Also i have made the username as my primary key in the database i.e., no two users can have the same username. So when the user taps on forgot password he enters his correct username and if it correct he enters the new password and it should replace his old password in the database.

This is the method i have defined to update the password

```
public void updateEntry(String userName, String password) {
    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
    updatedValues.put("PASSWORD", password);

    String where = "USERNAME = ?";
    db.update("LOGIN", updatedValues, where, new String[] { userName });
}
```

This is how i m calling the `updateEntry` method

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            String userName=forgot_username.getText().toString();
            String funame=loginDataBaseAdapter.getUserName(userName);
            String password=forgot_password.getText().toString();
            if (userName.equals(funame)) {
                if (forgot_password.equals(forgot_confirmpassword)){
                    loginDataBaseAdapter.updateEntry(userName,password);
                }

                Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this,"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this,"User Name is not correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
```

i m new to SQLite and can't figure out the problem.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: `can't figure out the problem` Me neither, if you don't explain **which** is the problem.

Comment: @LonnieZamora  see the password should update after i click the button update whose `onClick` i have shared but it does not update as when i go to check the database file i see no changes made.

Comment: @Omar I am prety sure that `loginDataBaseAdapter.updateEntry(userName,password);` returns an `int`. That `int` means how many rows have been affected by the change. Just add it to the `Toast` to verify that the change has been done. If you do it, post the code here so that we can check the code is correct.

Comment: what does `loginDataBaseAdapter.getUserName(userName);` do ?

Comment: @UDKOX thanks mate to look into my problem...the `updateEntry` in the `loginDataBaseAdapter` class method returns nothing as i have defined it as void in the code above

Comment: @njzk2 thanks to you too to look into my problem..the method `getUsername` in the `loginDataBaseAdapter` traverses all the user names in the database file and then if the username matches with the one in the database further the code executes..i have tried some test cases and this method is just working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add this method to your `LoginDataBaseAdapter` class

```
public boolean updateEntry(String userName, String password) {
  ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
  args.put("PASSWORD", password);
  return db.update("LOGIN", args, "USERNAME=" + userName, null) > 0;
}
```

Update your `onClick` method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String userName = forgot_username.getText().toString();
    String funame = loginDataBaseAdapter.getUserName(userName);
    String password = forgot_password.getText().toString();
    if (userName.equals(funame)) {
        if (forgot_password.equals(forgot_confirmpassword)) {
            if (loginDataBaseAdapter.updateEntry(userName,password)) {
                Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this,"User Name is not correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Let us know which Toast message is displayed.